# Create bidirectional 1:0..1 relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a model from an existing database and I noticed a problem.

I have the following tables

```
User
----------------
<pk> userId
<fk>  profileId

Profile
----------------
<pk> profileId
```

So every user has a profile.

I thought it would generate something like this

```
public class User
{
   public int userId {get; set;}
   public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class profile
{
   public int profileId {get; set;}
   public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

but instead the profile is like this

```
public class profile
{
   public int profileId {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

Entity thinks a profile can have many users because profile doesn't have a userId. So I have created a Unique Index on `profileId` in the user table (which ignore NULL values) but I still have the same problem.

How can I create a 1:0..1 relationship in Entity with the database first approach.

thank you

Comment: That's not a 0-to-1 relationship. It's a simple 1-to-1, but you have modeled a 1-to-n (any user can reference any profile, hence a certain profile can be referenced by many users). Why do you have a profile id? The `userId` would be sufficient as the PK and FK. Then EF probably gets the mapping correct.

Comment: I don't understand how could it work without a profileID. Could you explain please. Also, there's a unique index in the user table for the profileId. So nobody can have the same profile

Comment: In the end, it does not matter how the columns are named. The basic point is that the profile's PK is a FK to the user's PK.

Comment: but profileId is a foreign key. There's a relationship between the 2 tables

Comment: Just remove the `User.profileId` column (together with the FK constraint) and add a FK constraint of `Profile.profileId` to `User.userId`. That's the natural way of specifying 1-to-1 relationships.

Comment: So the userId has to be the same as the profileId? Add your answer I will accept it

Comment: Exactly. Kasper has already posted an answer. Accept this one.

Comment: Thank you. I thought you would like the points because you were the first one to find the solution

Comment: I have an error when I tried to create a user. It says Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'user' and 'profile'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations. I don't understand why because the model says a referential constraint user -> profile and the relation looks good (1-0..1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework does not understand that a unique key on the user table's profileId implicitly designates a 1:0..1 relationship.

If you really want to model a 1:0..1 relationship that Entity Framework understands, then there's no reason for the profile table to have it's own key. You can simple reuse the key from the user table. In that case the profileId column becomes both primary key and foreign key (pointing at the user table's userId). Your final database scheme will look like this

```
User
----
<pk>Id
userName

Profile
----
<pk><fk>UserId
profileName
```

Comment: I have an error when I tried to create a user. It says Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'user' and 'profile'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations. I don't understand why because the model says a referential constraint user -> profile and the relation looks good (1-0..1).